# How to correct GitHub token permissions in an action attempting to push to a GitHub NuGet store?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, nuget, github-actions, nuget-server

I have the following step in a shared workflow (lives in a repo within my org, not where it's called from):

```
- name: Publish and push image
        run: |
          dotnet pack ${{ inputs.csproj_path }} --configuration release -p:Version=${{ needs.gitversion.outputs.NuGetVersionV2 }} -p:WarningLevel=0
          dotnet nuget push ${{ inputs.release_folder_path }}*.nupkg -k ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} -s https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OrgName/index.json
```

I have tried it as above, with a passed in secret value, and directly using `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN`. I have also tried setting no explicit permissions, `permissions: write-all`, and setting the individual required permissions at the job and workflow levels.

Every time I do this, I get the following error:

```
Pushing Package.That.Does.Something.v2.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OrgName'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OrgName/
warn : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.
  Forbidden https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OrgName/ 320ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
```

I've run out of ideas of how to authenticate via a shared workflow. FYI, it works fine when the workflow is moved into the repository it is being called from. Any advice greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The calling workflow below...

```
permissions: write-all

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_publish:
    name: Build
    uses: OrgName/actions/.github/workflows/build-package-and-push-to-github-v1.yml@task/allow-tests
    with:
      csproj_path: './src/Package.That.Does.Something.csproj'
      release_folder_path: './src/bin/release/'
      dotnet_version: '3.1.x'
```

Comment: How do you call the workflow? Do you pass the secrets through?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I have tried both means. I've tried passing the secret in, and setting the permissions explicitly in the caller action. I've also tried not passing any secrets in and just explicitly setting the permissions in the shared workflow

Comment: A reusable workflow can't elevate permissions from what it gets. If you do something wrong in your YAML, we can't tell because we can't see it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. added the calling workflow in the question. I've tried it with write-all, and specific package permissions

Comment: And how are you using `GITHUB_TOKEN` in the reusable workflow?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Edited the question to make it clearer again. Its at the very top: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} passed as the -k param

Comment: Try setting the permissions in the calling workflow at the *job* level, instead of the workflow level.

Comment: Updated to write-all at the job level and still seeing the 403 :(

Comment: you didn't mention if you read github's docs. Just in case it helps, here are their docs, where they have a section specifically about authentication: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry